# Understanding callback methods

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am still confused about callback methods (new to OOP). One definition I found was: "A callback method in java is a method that gets called when an event occurs". What exactly decides when the method will be called? For example, in android,  the activity class has an onCreate() callback method that executes whenever an Activity is created, but what code controls this?
Is the doInBackground method of the AsyncTask class also a callback method that executes whenever a  foo.execute() is called, where foo is an AsyncTask object?

Comment: Android Activity has a lifecycle .After its created untill destroyed there are some methods which called by android os automatically.You can use these mehtods to handle the things that yo  ant in those status of activity

Answer (score 1):

I see it quite simple like this: lets say you give me your phone number and I'll call you at sunrise. You don't have to worry about how I get up and call your "call-back number", as long as you trust me.

Its the same with a callback method. If the API documents you can supply a method and it will be called when a certain event happens, you don't have to worry about how that's done. Thats the responsibility of the creator of the API.

Comment: Android os handle the callback methods

Comment: You're probably right, I'm just saying it doesn't matter